# Occasional IOException when creating a CSV file 'The process cannot access the file...'

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop, ioexception

I'm creating a CSV (with ';' as seperator) file by using the Office.Interop.Excell library.

Following code works fine on my computer but one of my clients sometimes get's the IO.Exception: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'.

The weird thing is that this error is not allways popping up, sometimes it works, sometimes it doesnt...

What could be the cause of this occasional IO.Exception for my client. This is my code:

```
public static void GenerateCsvFile(DataSet ds, string paramFileFullPath, Dictionary<string, string[]> tableHeaders)
    {
        object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        var excel = new Application { DisplayAlerts = false };
        Workbook workbook = null;
        try
        {
            workbook = excel.Application.Workbooks.Add(true);

            foreach (System.Data.DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
                AddTableSheet(ref workbook, ref excel, dt, true, tableHeaders[dt.TableName], false);

            workbook.SaveAs(paramFileFullPath, XlFileFormat.xlTextMSDOS, missing, missing, false, false,
              XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlNoChange, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing);
        }
        finally
        {
            CleanupExcel(excel, workbook);
        }

        File.WriteAllText(paramFileFullPath, File.ReadAllText(paramFileFullPath).Replace("\t", ";"));
    }
```

I guess the error sometimes come from the line:

`File.WriteAllText(paramFileFullPath, File.ReadAllText(paramFileFullPath).Replace("\t", ";"));`

Is there perhaps something wrong with the way i'm cleaning/closing Excel ?

```
private static void CleanupExcel(Application excel, Workbook workbook)
    {
        if (excel == null)
            return;

        excel.DisplayAlerts = false;
        excel.Quit();

        if (workbook != null)
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excel);
    }
```

And how come that this allways works for me, but on the PC of my client it only works like 1 out of 5 times...

Comment: Workbook  close and dispose

Comment: You have not ReleaseComObject all COM objects (e.g. excel.Application.Workbooks). See https://ausdotnet.wordpress.com/2008/05/26/com-interop-principle-2-fear-the-period/ .

Comment: As a quick and dirty, add GC.Collect(); GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(); at the end of your CleanupExcel method.

Comment: .Close() and .Dispose() your IDisposable objects (workbook). You could do it in your CleanupExcel function.

Answer (score 2):

> but one of my clients sometimes get's the IO.Exception: 'The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process'.

How much should I bet that the underlying problem is that said client is keeping the file open in Excel while trying to run your code? ;)

Comment: No, that's not the case... I've tested it myself on the client's computer

Comment: Then try one of the numerous programs to list file locks.